# connect to Nest Streaming with Java web socket

Tags: java, websocket, firebase, netty, nest-api

I'm trying to connect to the Nest streaming firebase interface with Java (not android). From what I can tell, I should be using a websocket for that. I implemented my websocket call in Netty and that seems to be working properly - at least it connects. I get this response:

```
{"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1457637023192,"v":"5","h":"firebase-apiserver03-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553","s":"session572852927"}}}
```

I used a browser tool to verify the result and I get the same thing. 
The problem is that I don't know what to do with that information. This is the only bit of information that comes over the socket.

There are a couple other discussions here that mention similar data, but no one really said, what the solution was. At first I thought it was a redirect, but the url included in the data is the same one in my original request, so it can't be a redirect.

Thanks

Comment: Can you hit us with the code you're using?

Comment: Have you been able to make anything of the data, I'm currently stuck at the same place.